# How to set up OAuth2.0 for flutter iOS app (redirect URL?)

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm a beginner developer. I am writing an iOS application using Flutter. I need to use an API to identify my user. The provider of that API asks me to send them a redirect URL. From what I understand, when an user identify themselves on my app, a request will be send to the API provider, and once the user is correctly identified, the API provider want to know where to send the user (the redirect URL). But I want the user to stay on my app.

How should I set up that ?
Thanks

Comment: search `oauth` in pub.dev, and look at, for example, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to implement this is via the AppAuth pattern, where the app invokes an `ASWebAuthenticationSession` window, which is a secure browser. From a UX viewpoint it looks integrated and remains a part of the app.

As a next step, maybe have a look at my [iOS AppAuth Basic Tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/ios-setup/) to see what this looks like. The simplest option is a private URI scheme based redirect URL that looks like this:

```
net.openid.appauthdemo:/oauth2redirect
```

Once the concepts are understood, and your team has reviewed the user experience etc, the next step would be to implement this behaviour in Flutter.